# Is there a way in Python to extract values from a list of nested dictionaries?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of nested dictionaries looking like this one:

```
list_1 = [{'one':{'two':{'three':{'a':10,
                                 'b':20,
                                 'c':30,
                                 'd':[1,2,3,4]}}}}]
```

I would like to get a dataframe that looks like the following:

| key | values |
| --- | --- |
| d | 1 |
| d | 2 |
| d | 3 |
| d | 4 |

Thanks for your help, munch needed and appreciated :)

Comment: Can you explain how you reached the expected output? what happened to `one`, `two`, `three`, `a`, `b`, `c`. What if there are more keys on `one`'s level?

Comment: That's the whole point... I don't know hot reach the output :( . You are absolutely right, there are more keys on "one" 's level. I've seen the .get function should help in this case but I was not able make it work

Comment: I think you misunderstood @Ch3steR's question. What he meant I think is WHY this output should be generated from this input? What's the logic?

Comment: I know the structure of the nested dictionaries, and the keys name. I would like to get a code that can extract the list within "d" which is contained in "three", "two" and "one"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

list_1 = [{"one": {"two": {"three": {"a": 10,
                                     "b": 20,
                                     "c": 30,
                                     "d": [1, 2, 3, 4]}}}}]


df = pd.DataFrame({"key": "d", 
                   "value": list_1[0]["one"]["two"]["three"]["d"]})

print(df)

>>>   key  values
>>> 0   d      1
>>> 1   d      2
>>> 2   d      3
>>> 3   d      4
```